# How to trigger an azure logic app on AWS S3 file upload?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-s3, azure-logic-apps

I am looking to find a way to trigger a logic app once a file is uploaded to my S3 bucket in AWS. The integration according to the image below and the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/amazons3/#when-an-s3-object-is-updated) is expecting an object key which means it is only able to trigger once a specific object is updated
[image]

Is there a way I can trigger a logic app on ANY S3 uploads and get the metadata of that specific object?

Comment: If you can't get that working, you could always use a Lambda function to catch the event and then send it on to a LogicApp that's triggered by a HTTP request ... https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days working on the solution, there is no possible way from azure side to get informed of any uploads to a S3 bucket as the time of writing this.
I was however able to handle it via a Lambda function as the comment from @Skin suggested. A lambda function which is triggered via a S3 upload and it is calling Logic App via HTTPs. of course, the Lambda has some configuration to it in VPC to be able to call external resources.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Azure logic app with cron to fetch data every 5 minutes or so..
2. Use S3 connector and get the S3 content.
3. Use the data collector connector and move this either into store account or workspace.

[image]